# how to create FAB reveal animation like Google keep and Inbox by gmail

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to create FAB animations like shown in Google design guidelines such as circular reveal, morph animations (google keep and inbox) in API Level 15. I used google design support library to add FAB icon to my app.

I would appreciate your help in this regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The FAB animation is actually a simple scale animation that you can write yourself, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="250" />
</set>
```

That goes in an xml in the "anim" folder. 
And then you animate the button in the java code:

```
final Animation mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.animation_name);
yourFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //It has to be invisible before here
yourFab.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but how can I show sub menu on tap of Fab icon?

Comment: @Nagendra If I understood correctly: you create another FAB (invisible), and you make it visible, with the same animation, on the click of the first FAB. If there are more than one, you don't show them at the same time, but with a delay from the closest one to the furthest one (use Button.postDelayed())